# FedEx Tracking Api

Tags: node.js, alfresco-share

I'am new to the Web Services.
Do we need to open an FedEx account to access their Tracking Api.
Here ,I got the Test Credentials but FedEx throwing Invalid Reply as Error. 
I just logged in to FedEx I went to Develop and Test option here I got the test credentials.
 Can any one please provide me the necessary steps to open an FedEx account.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can start working with test credentials,
Once you are ready to move to the production you can call Fedex(they have good support) or request production key on your fedex account dashboard. 
You will need :

- Access Key
- Password
- Account Number
- Meter Number